# could somebody give out some basic examples of this code?

Tags: c

I really don't understands this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argument c, char *argument v[])
{

  return 0;
}
```

What does this code mean? How does it converts to other formation of coding?

Comment: Can you please be little more clear?

Comment: That code means: "Tell the operating system that I ignored all of its arguments and exited with code `0`"

Comment: Does this compile, i.e. `char *argument v[]` is in error

Comment: Remove both instances of the word 'argument', change the resulting function signature from (int c, char* v[]) to (int argc, char* argv[]) for style.  And your program does nothing, but return 0 (which is linux for true, btw).

Answer (score 2):

This is (almost) the simplest C/C++ program. (It works for both languages.) It does nothing other than return 0, which signifies successful execution.

It should read

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

Comment: What do you mean "It should read?" Is that the only right way?

Comment: @nispio: Well, look at the question.  The code there is wrong.

Comment: There are other correct ways, but the question asker's version is not correct, since it has "argument c".

The version I give is pretty standard, and I don't think I've ever seen another version. Presumably you can rename argc and argv without consequence.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't notice that there was a space in the variable names in the original question.  I thought that you were specifying that it must be `char **argv` instead of `char *argumentv[]`.  Either should compile just fine.